# How to equip the right items to companions?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will Jordis the Sword-Maiden ever use the bow that I made for her?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56533/will-jordis-the-sword-maiden-ever-use-the-bow-that-i-made-for-her)

I have a new companion, but I had the bug with Sven also. I'm now using Mjoll, and I gave her my old Glass Bow, and she uses a bow, but it always shows up as a wooden hunting bow.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? I've tried taking it out of her inventory, putting it back in etc, without any change.

I should also say that the glass bow is the only bow in her inventory. I guess it's using the Glass Bow stats, but is bugged visually?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/56584/7508) to my [similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/56533/7508) may help:

> ... followers who start with any kind of bow in their inventory are
>   bugged so that placing a different bow in their inventory will have no
>   effect. It may look as if they equipped the new bow, but the follower
>   will switch back to their default bow as soon as combat starts, even
>   if that bow was removed from their inventory.

Comment: I don't recall Mjoll starting with a bow though. I guess it's just a bug in the game, how frustrating. I guess I'll archive that glass bow then. Or will they have no bow if there isn't one in their inventory?